# Compare two times in C

Tags: c, datetime, compare

How do I compare time in C? 
My program is getting the last modified time of 2 files, then compare that time to see which time is the latest.
Is there a function that compares time for you, or you have to create one yourself? This is my get time function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void getFileCreationTime(char *path) {
    struct stat attr;
    stat(path, &attr);
    printf("Last modified time: %s", ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
}
```

Comment: It might be operating system specific. I guess you are using Linux or some POSIX system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `difftime(time1, time0)` from `time.h` to get the difference between two times. This calculates `time1 - time0` and returns a `double` representing the difference in seconds. If it's positive, then `time1` is later than `time0`; if negative, `time0` is later; if 0, they're the same.

Answer (score 6):

You can compare two `time_t` values to find which is newer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static time_t getFileModifiedTime(const char *path)
{
    struct stat attr;
    if (stat(path, &attr) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s: last modified time: %s", path, ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
        return attr.st_mtime;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file1 file2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    time_t t1 = getFileModifiedTime(argv[1]);
    time_t t2 = getFileModifiedTime(argv[2]);
    if (t1 < t2)
        printf("%s is older than %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    else if (t1 > t2)
        printf("%s is newer than %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    else
        printf("%s is the same age as %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to know the difference between the values in seconds, then you need to use [`difftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/difftime.html) officially, but in practice you can simply subtract the two `time_t` values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below method

```
double difftime (time_t end, time_t beginning);
```

It returns the time difference in seconds. You can find [example here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/)

Answer (score 2):

my code:

```
char * findLeastFile(char *file1, char *file2){
    struct stat attr1, attr2;
    if (stat(file1, &attr1) != 0 || stat(file2, &attr2) != 0)
    {
        printf("file excetion");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(difftime(attr1.st_mtime,attr2.st_mtime) >= 0)
        return file1;
    else 
        return file2;

}
```